# Smartphone with DAB+ digital radio builtin

Tags: smartphones

Back in 2016, the LG (G) Stylus 2 was the first phone with a builtin DAB+ radio. It has now been discontinued. Are there any more recent mobile phones with DAB+ support? The newer LG models do not seem to have it.

I know that there are USB dongles for DAB+ reception with Android devices. This is not what I am looking for.